# Lightroom Multi-Catalog Syncing/Management

Tags: software, lightroom, post-processing, photo-editing, lightroom-catalog

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the best way to synchronize Adobe Lightroom databases between two computers?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/1558/what-is-the-best-way-to-synchronize-adobe-lightroom-databases-between-two-comput)

I'm looking for an application to **manage multiple Lightroom catalogs** for me - I typically edit photos on my desktop, but when I'm away (on vacation, etc.) I dump pictures to my laptop and edit there.

This gives me the problem with having two simultaneous catalogs of images. What I would love to be able to do is come home and **sync my laptop LR catalog to that on the desktop**.

Even better, I'd love to be able to "check out" images and presets (I realize that these are just stored on the file system and not in the actual catalog file, but I still want the feature) from the desktop catalog to the laptop one. Essentially, I'm looking for **source control for Lightroom catalogs**.

**Does anything like this exist?** I have exhausted all other internet sources I can think of.

**If nothing exists**, I plan on writing my own: in that case, **would this be a useful application** for you, and if so, what features would you look for in it?

Thanks!